# Computing "evidence" probability with Naive Bayes classification

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, naivebayes

I just coded a Naive Bayes classifier for text classification that is giving me expected results. My features are words, and my classes are text classes. I've coded a multinomial Naive Bayes classifier.

However I would prefer my classifier to output real percentage values ...

To do so I've got to compute the evidence probability as explained in [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier).

I've got no problem to compute the prior and the conditional probabilities. However I do not know how to compute the evidence probability P(X). And the few documentations talking about it are not very clear.

I've tried :

1. P(X) as the product of P(Xi) where Xi is my feature (basically it is the product of the percentage of feature within the pool).
2. P(X) as the sum of P(Ck) * (product of P(Xi/Ck) for all classes.

None of these solutions give me correct percentages ...

Do you know how to compute the evidence probability in my case?

Comment: OK, I just found out how to fix my problem. I just normalized by the sum of probabilities and it scaled my output in percentage ... Simply.

Comment: Please add your answer and close the question.